# Major Complaint

Tags: support

Just joined the site a few hours ago and have been barred from asking questions for 2 days - the reason given was that one of my two questions upset the community. It was suggested that I visit links such as "how to ask a question". You guys take yourselves way too seriously; your site is about science fiction not how to cure cancer. I think, in future, I'll just use Google or the Wikis.

Comment: For more info on *why*, please see [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: Yes, we *Are* a site that takes ourselves seriously, only because it's one that's designed to provide high-quality and definitive answers to questions. We are not a forum or a discussion site. Please don't be offended at the actions of users here. You're welcome to ask for help if you'd like, we're all here to help (even if it doesn't seem like it).

Comment: Also, note that the same software runs _all_ Stack Exchange sites, not just SF/F. That includes very high-volume sites like Stack Overflow. The question ban you ran into is a feature of the software, regardless of how much or how little "importance" you assign to the topic of the site.

Comment: In _future_, you definitely should use Google and Wikias before asking here. There's no point at all in asking questions that can be answered by quoting the relevant Wikia article - this doesn't contribute anything new to the knowledge pool, and such questions indeed get downvoted fairly regularly. The Stack Exchange model (as per [tour]) is better suited for things not covered by Wikias.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Yes research is always a good thing, but we can't always expect people to find exactly what they are looking or even know about all the wikias out there. Adding correct answers here *does* add to the knowledge pool, the *Stack Exchange* pool.

Comment: it is indeed taken a bit seriously because the idea is that when you go to Google - you'll end up here :)

Answer (score 18):

I'm very sorry to hear that you're not having a good time on your first day with us. Let's have a quick review of your actions so far;

Q. "[Genetics and Origins of Mutants/Inhumans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/165502/genetics-and-origins-of-mutants-inhumans)" - Rather too vague and immediately identified as a duplicate of one of the site's most viewed questions. I'm pretty sure it came up on your "suggested" questions list when posting which means that you've had to ignore it. If it hadn't been closed as a duplicate, it would have certainly been closed for being too broad.

Q. "[Can Wolverine be considered a mutant?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/165497/can-wolverine-be-considered-a-mutant)" - On the face of it, possibly an interesting question (if you could offer any reason for us to think that he might not be) but a cursory search reveals that he is indeed a mutant and has always been so. Your question suggests a distinct lack of research effort which may account for its downvotes.

A. "[Need help finding an old tv-show (80's/90's)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/165495/need-help-finding-an-old-tv-show-80s-90s/165515#165515)" - Your answer here is vague and unhelpful. The OP is asking for an episode to be identified. You've told them the name of an alternative anthology show and suggest that they "google it". This has attracted zero upvotes and three downvotes.

---

While it's true that we're not curing cancer, your contribution to our little corner of the internet hasn't been particularly well received by the community thus far. The rate limit is intended to give you time to review the site's policies and maybe have a look around at the way in which others are asking and answering questions. It's also there to protect the site from new users (like yourselves) making contributions that aren't helpful and thus attracting even more negative attention.

Comment: I'd like to add that having a question closed as a duplicate is not a bad thing. It just means that is has been asked before and already has an answer.

Comment: @SQB - Although in this case it was a variety of close reasons. Dupe was merely the one that got to five votes first

Comment: Of course. Regardless, I think it's important to point out to newbies that closing as a duplicate is _not a bad thing_. That aspect tends to get lost.